# How to get the total number of specific files in a directory containing subdirectories?

Tags: python

The following python code counts the number of total files I have in a directory which contains multiple subdirectories. The result prints the subdirectory name along with the number of files it contains.

How can I modify this so that:

- It only looks for a specific file extension (i.e. "*.shp")
- It provides both the number of ".shp" files in each subdirectory and a final count of all ".shp" files

Here is the code:

```
import os
path = 'path/to/directory'
folders = ([name for name in os.listdir(path)])
for folder in folders:
    contents = os.listdir(os.path.join(path,folder))
    print(folder,len(contents))
```

Comment: Not a literal copy of the other, but pretty darn close. Add recursion and you have your answer.

Comment: @cwallenpoole - Thanks, I'll take a look =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the .endswith() function on strings. This is handy for recognizing extensions. You could loop through the contents to find these files then as follows.

```
targets = []
for i in contents:
    if i.endswith(extension):
        targets.append(i)
print(folder, len(contents))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments and answer, this is the code I used (feel free to flag my question as a duplicate of the linked question if it is too close):

```
import os
path = 'path/to/directory'
folders = ([name for name in os.listdir(path)])
targets = []
for folder in folders:
    contents = os.listdir(os.path.join(path,folder))
    for i in contents:
        if i.endswith('.shp'):
            targets.append(i)
    print(folder, len(contents))

print "Total number of files = " + str(len(targets))
```

Comment: I would have started with *os..path.walk()* function and *os.path.splitext()* is cleaner than *endswith()*.

Comment: @guidot - Thanks for your comment, but why would _os.path.splitext()_ be cleaner than _endswith()_?

Comment: Since a) you explicitly state, that you want to compare the extension instead of hiding this in a string b) less side effects if a file exists named *.shp* (unix-style name starting with dot, no extension intended).

Comment: @guidot - Thanks for your tip, I'll try and implement that =)